# Construct a circle of nested squares

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas

I want to construct a circle of nested squares like this:

[image: circleOfSquares]

In the moment, I am programming in JavaScript/HTML5 canvas. This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Circle of squares</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var r = 150, u = 20, nests = 200;       //radius in pixels, circumference in squares, nests in squares
var w = r;                              //any number != 0

function getNewW()
{
    if(u < 3)
        alert("Error: u < 3 (" + u + " < 3)!");

    var tangents = new Array(new Array(0, w/2), new Array(Math.sin((1/u*360)*(Math.PI/180))*(w/2), -Math.cos((1/u*360)*(Math.PI/180))*(w/2)));
    var sta = new Array(new Array(r, 0), new Array(Math.cos((1/u*360)*(Math.PI/180))*r, Math.sin((1/u*360)*(Math.PI/180))*r));
    var end = new Array(new Array(sta[0][0]+tangents[0][0], sta[0][1]+tangents[0][1]), new Array(sta[1][0]+tangents[1][0], sta[1][1]+tangents[1][1]));
    var pts = new Array(sta[0], end[0], sta[1], end[1]);
    var intersect = new Array(((pts[0][0]*pts[1][1]-pts[0][1]*pts[1][0])*(pts[2][0]-pts[3][0]) - (pts[0][0]-pts[1][0])*(pts[2][0]*pts[3][1]-pts[2][1]*pts[3][0])) / ((pts[0][0]-pts[1][0])*(pts[2][1]-pts[3][1]) - (pts[0][1]-pts[1][1])*(pts[2][0]-pts[3][0])), ((pts[0][0]*pts[1][1]-pts[0][1]*pts[1][0])*(pts[2][1]-pts[3][1]) - (pts[0][1]-pts[1][1])*(pts[2][0]*pts[3][1]-pts[2][1]*pts[3][0])) / ((pts[0][0]-pts[1][0])*(pts[2][1]-pts[3][1]) - (pts[0][1]-pts[1][1])*(pts[2][0]-pts[3][0])));        //Formula from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection


    //distTo0 should be equal to distTo1
    var distTo0 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(sta[0][0]-intersect[0], 2) + Math.pow(sta[0][1]-intersect[1], 2));
    var distTo1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(sta[1][0]-intersect[0], 2) + Math.pow(sta[1][1]-intersect[1], 2));
    if(Math.round(distTo0*100)/100 != Math.round(distTo1*100)/100)
        alert("Error: distTo0 != distTo1 (" + distTo0 + " != " + distTo1 + ")!");

    return distTo0*2;
}

function start()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("outputCanvas");

    canvas.setAttribute("width",  600);
    canvas.setAttribute("height", 600);

    if(canvas.getContext)
    {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.translate(300, 300);

        w = getNewW();
        for(var i=0; i<u; i++)
        {
            ctx.rotate((1/u*360)*(Math.PI/180));
            ctx.fillRect(r, -w/2, w, w);
        }

        for(var j=1; j<nests; j++)
        {
            var oldr = r;
            var temp1 = 1/(10*j+1);
            while(r+w > oldr)        //This is the while-loop that makes the program slow
            {
                r -= temp1;
                w = getNewW();
            }
            if(r < 0)       //When the radius gets smaller than 0, the center is reached -> no new squares have to be drawn
                break;

            var temp2 = (1/u*360)*(Math.PI/180);
            for(var i=0; i<u; i++)
            {
                ctx.rotate(temp2);
                ctx.fillRect(r, -w/2, w, w);
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body id="main" onload="start()">
<canvas style="border:1px #000000 solid;" width="0" height="0" id="outputCanvas">Canvas not supported...</canvas>
<div id="info"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But because I don't have a formula for the solution, I use a while-loop to get closer and closer to the solution (until it has reached zero because of float-inaccuracy), that's why it's quite slow.
So, what **formula** can be used to calculate the width of the next square inside the (thought) circle and, if necessary, how could the code be optimized elsewhere?

Comment: What exactly is `nests` counting?  The number of squares along a ray from the center of the circle to its outer edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is quite easy :
What are the parameters ?
• The start radius of your circle.
• The end radius of your circle.
• The number of square per circle.

Then what do you need to compute ?
• The rotation to be performed between two circles : easy ,that's just a full rotation divided by the number of square per circle :

```
var angle = 2 * Math.PI / squaresPerCircle;
```

• The size of each square, given the current radius. Easy also : compute the circumference of the current circle (2*PI*radius), then the size of one square is approximately this circumference divided by the number of squares (since you want to fill the circle) :

```
squareSize = 2 * Math.PI * currentRadius / squaresPerCircle;
```

approximation is good enough even for like 10 squares per circles.

( 
   Otherwise the 'real' way to get the height when you have radius and angle is done with :

```
squareSize = 2 * currentRadius * Math.tan(angle/2);
```

[image]

)

Snippet :

```js
// parameters
var startRadius = 5;
var maxRadius = 200;
var squaresPerCircle = 20;

function start() {
  // boilerplate
  var canvas = document.getElementById("outputCanvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = 600;
  canvas.height = 600;
  //
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);

  var currentRadius = startRadius;
  var angle = 2 * Math.PI / squaresPerCircle;
  // loop on each ring
  do {
    squareSize = 2 * Math.PI * currentRadius / squaresPerCircle;
    // squareSize = 2 * currentRadius * Math.tan(angle/2);      
    ctx.save();
    // loop on every square of a single ring
    for (var cIndex = 0; cIndex < squaresPerCircle; cIndex++) {
      ctx.fillRect(currentRadius, -squareSize / 2,
        squareSize, squareSize);
      ctx.rotate(angle);
    };
    ctx.restore();
    currentRadius += squareSize;
  } while (currentRadius < maxRadius);

  ctx.restore();
}

onload = start;
```

```html
<canvas style="border:1px #000000 solid;" width="0" height="0" id="outputCanvas">Canvas not supported...</canvas>
```

Comment: Wow, a short, comprehensive and straightforward answer with an exact solution at the end! Thank you very much!

Comment: Wait,... what is that `squareSize *= 1.2;` at the end of the do-while-loop for?

Comment: You're welcome ! ( i did various attempt just for fun, just forgot to remove the squareSize*=1.2 after ! ) ! Happy Coding !

Answer (score 6):

Near the center of the circle, where the squares are small enough, you can approximate the length of the side (*w*) by the arc length - that is, how long one *u*th of the inner circle would be if you drew it as an actual circle.  That's just the angle in radians (2 *π*/*u*) times the radius of the circle that goes through the inner corners of the square. Since you have `r` varying in your code, I'll call the specific radius value under consideration at a single moment *r2*; that makes the arc length this:

```
w_approx = (2 * Math.PI / u) * r2
```

But for most of the squares in your picture, the difference between that and the actual value of *w* is too great; if you use that as the side length, you'll get overlapping squares.  Fortunately, we can calculate the true value of *w* directly, too; it just requires a little trigonometry.

If you draw lines from the inner corners of the square to the center of the circle, those two lines plus the inner side of the square form a triangle.  We know how long those two lines we just drew are; they're equal to the inner radius.  We don't know how long the third side is - that's the value of *w* we're looking for - but we do know the angle opposite it. Those three pieces of information are enough to calculate *w*.

Here's a picture to show what I'm talking about:

[image]

The angle at the center of the circle, labeled *α* (alpha) in the picture, is just one *u*th of a full circle, which is 2 *π* /*u* radians (or 360/*u* degrees, but the trig functions all expect radians):

```
alpha = 2 * Math.PI / u
```

The other two angles of the triangle are equal (they have to be, because they're opposite sides that are of equal length), so they're both labeled *β*. Since the three angles of a triangle always add up to *π* radians (or 180º), we can calculate *β*; it's equal to (*π* - *α*)/2 radians:

```
beta = (Math.PI - alpha)/2
```

By the [Law of Sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines), if you divide the length of any side of any triangle by the sine of the angle opposite that side, the result is the same no matter which of the three sides you picked. That tells us that *w*/**sin** *α* must be the same as *r2*/**sin** *β*.  Solving that equation for *w* gets us this:

```
w = r2 * Math.sin(alpha) / Math.sin(beta)
```

Comment: Such an amazing answer. *This* is what StackOverflow was made for.

Comment: Aww, shucks, @Qix.  Thanks.